# How to Save the imageView of a favorite image in android studio using shared preferences?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

i have a favorite feature in my application. when a user clicks on the favorite button to favorite a certain shop or item, the image of the heart goes from outlined to inlined, similar to the way the like button works in Instagram.

Now it works fine and changes when i click it and everything, but when i move to another page or close down the application, it wont remember that this is a saved item or shop.

how can i save  the `ImageView` after it is clicked, and someone moves to another activity or closes the app?

full code:

```
details_fave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           Task<QuerySnapshot> f =  fStore.collection("Favorites")
                    .whereEqualTo("shopPID", SID).whereEqualTo("usersID", UID)
                    .get()
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = task.getResult();
                                if (querySnapshot.isEmpty()) {

                                    details_fave.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_favorite_24);
                                    clicked = !clicked;
                                    Map<String, Object> fav = new HashMap<>();


                                    fStore.collection("Favorites").add(fav).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                                            Toast.makeText(DetailsActivity.this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                            Toast.makeText(DetailsActivity.this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    });
                                }else {
                                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                        document.getReference().delete();
                                        Toast.makeText(DetailsActivity.this, "Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    }
                                    details_fave.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_outline_favorite_border_o);


                            }

                            }
                        }
                    });


            }

    });
```

my code favorite image code:

```java
details_fave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        if (querySnapshot.isEmpty()) {
            details_fave.setImageResource(
                R.drawable.ic_baseline_favorite_24
            );
        }else{  
            details_fave.setImageResource(
                R.drawable.ic_outline_favorite_border_o
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: you don't need to save imageview, you can have a boolean variable saved in shared preferences  and upon that value you can mark your heart outlined or inlined .

Comment: yes thats my question, how?

Comment: You are using listview or recyclerview to display your data right ?

Comment: a relative layout

Comment: No I meant that where are you using this code snippet? Can you post your complete code here of this relevant class ?

Comment: full code updated in the question..

Comment: Ok you are using your code in your activity. Let me post an answer

Comment: I have posted the answer you can take a look make changes accordingly.